# Access datatemplate element in a listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have an image control generated by a datatemplate in a listbox. How can I access this image through code? I tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) but as I am working on a metro app therefore cannot set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem.

The xaml I have is:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="options_stack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,569,0,33" Width="603" Background="#FF603C74" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="options_image" Source = "{Binding}" Stretch="Fill" Width="166" MaxHeight="156" MaxWidth="166" MinHeight="156" MinWidth="166" Tapped="apply_image_tapped" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to get the path of tapped image so here is what I did:

```
    Image tappedImage = new Image();
    tappedImage = e.OriginalSource as Image;
    textbox.Text = tappedImage.DataContext.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what you are trying to achieve by accessing the image. You can bind its property to the view model and control it with a view model. You could also put the Image in a UserControl and handle anything you want in there. You could use an attached behavior or you can use VisualTreeHelper to scan the visual tree of the ListBox (though that might be slow).

Comment: I can expand more on one of these or link to some more info if I know more of the context.

Comment: This listbox is populated at run time by different images. What I want to do is to find out path of a particular image when it is tapped by the user. What would you suggest now?